# I was trouble with Highcharts in x-axis series name and y-axis values name i don't want this two name's?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

HTML

```
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

  <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

JS

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'X axis labels are disabled'
},
xAxis: {

    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
},

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, [enter link description here][1]194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/jfg8w3f9/

in x-axis i want disable in series name and y-axis disable in valve name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make legend `enable:false`, and yAxis title `text:''`

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/gqh45zbx/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'X axis labels are disabled'
    },
    xAxis: {

        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {

        title: {
            text: ''
        },
    },
    legend:{
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Header name X-axis labels are disabled i want the header name outside of the graph

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/gqh45zbx/1/) is this according to requirement

Answer (score 0):

You may remove x and y-axis's labels and values by setting  `labels:{enabled: false}` and `title:{text:null}`. Also hide the chart legend by inserting this in your series `showInLegend: false,`.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfg8w3f9/1/)

Sample JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'X axis labels are disabled'
    },
    xAxis: {

        labels:{enabled: false},
        title: {
                text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
    labels:{enabled: false},
     title: {
            text: null
     }
    },

    series: [{
            showInLegend: false, 
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```